# Persistence of variables within a single session

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working with Reinforcement Learning and would like to store my examples within the TF graph to avoid moving data between python and TF.  I thought I could use a TF.Variable() as it should persist for the entire session and simply add a sample on the end when needed.  Here is an example of one of the approaches:

```
import tensorflow as tf

initx = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
         [4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0],
         [7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 8.0]]

x = tf.get_variable("x",dtype=tf.float32,validate_shape=False,initializer=tf.constant(initx))
xappend = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,4])
#xappend = tf.get_variable("xappend",shape=[1,4],dtype=tf.float32,validate_shape=False)

x = tf.concat(0,[x,xappend])

with tf.Session('') as session:
  session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())    
  print session.run([x],feed_dict={xappend:[[-1.0,98.0,97.0,96.0]] })
  print session.run([x],feed_dict={xappend:[[-2.0,98.0,97.0,96.0]] })
  print session.run([x],feed_dict={xappend:[[-3.0,98.0,97.0,96.0]] })
  print session.run([x],feed_dict={xappend:[[-4.0,98.0,97.0,96.0]] })
```

My thought is this should concatenate the "xappend" value to the end of tensor "x" and grow as each observation is added.  This is not what seems to happen.  For each run, I get the initialized value plus the xappend value, just a single instance of xappend.  I can't seem to get the -1,-2,-3,-4 to append to the end of the tensor within the session.  Here is the output:

```
[array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],  
   [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],  
   [  7.,   8.,   9.,   8.],  
   [ -1.,  98.,  97.,  96.]], dtype=float32)]  
[array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],  
   [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],  
   [  7.,   8.,   9.,   8.],  
   [ -2.,  98.,  97.,  96.]], dtype=float32)]  
[array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],  
   [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],  
   [  7.,   8.,   9.,   8.],  
   [ -3.,  98.,  97.,  96.]], dtype=float32)]  
[array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],  
   [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],  
   [  7.,   8.,   9.,   8.],  
   [ -4.,  98.,  97.,  96.]], dtype=float32)]
```

I have tried another approach within the session and get the same unexpected results:

```
...
update = tf.assign(xappend, [[-1.0,98.0,97.0,96.0]], validate_shape=False)
print session.run([update])
print session.run([x])
update = tf.assign(xappend, [[-2.0,98.0,97.0,96.0]], validate_shape=False)
print session.run([update])
print session.run([x])
...
```

I know that when I have weights, they persist between calls within the same session.  I am sure it has something to do with the size change with the tf.concat() function that doesn't allow persistence of the "x" variable in this graph.

Any ideas what could be going wrong with this approach?  Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. If you want to modify a Variable, you have to create an assign op. This operation will be run in `sess.run()` and will update the content of the Variable.

Here the trick is that when assigning the Variable, you modify its shape. You have to use `tf.assign` with argument `validate_shape=False`. This was hinted in the doc:

> If you want to change the shape of a variable later you have to use an assign Op with validate_shape=False

But the documentation for `tf.assign` does not exist.

---

```py
initx = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
         [4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0],
         [7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 8.0]]

x = tf.get_variable("x",dtype=tf.float32,validate_shape=False,initializer=tf.constant(initx))
xappend = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,4])

new_x = tf.concat(0, [x, xappend])
append_op = tf.assign(x, new_x, validate_shape=False)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    sess.run(append_op, feed_dict={xappend:[[-1.0,98.0,97.0,96.0]] })
    sess.run(append_op, feed_dict={xappend:[[-2.0,98.0,97.0,96.0]] })
    sess.run(append_op, feed_dict={xappend:[[-3.0,98.0,97.0,96.0]] })
    sess.run(append_op, feed_dict={xappend:[[-4.0,98.0,97.0,96.0]] })

    sess.run(x)  # should give you the expected result, of shape [7, 4]
```

---

However, this code will likely not be very efficient because you constantly change the shape of the Variable.

Better ways will be either to store a python list, or (better) to use a fixed size array of shape `[max_length, 4]` where you specify the `max_lenght` argument in advance, and fill the array row by row.

Comment: Thank you Olivier, that works.  So the value of "x" returned in my example was some form of local variable, it isn't clear when it resets back to the original "x"?  Is this assign only required because of the shape change as "weight & bias" type variables seem to persist without any visible assign (maybe something buried in the apply gradients?).

Comment: In your recommendation, are you recommending a Tensor [max,4]?  That would work, but I am not sure how to insert say "xappend" into [5,], is there a tensor function that now allows numpy type indexing now?

Comment: I think changing constantly the shape of the Variable is very time consuming. With shape `[max, 4]` you could insert each new state in a given index with [`scatter_add(x, indice, new_state)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#scatter_add)

Comment: The issue in your code was that `x` was the concatenation of a Variable (which content never changes), and a placeholder. In TensorFlow you cannot do `x = x + 1` to update a Variable, you need to use the `assign()` method